# Send formatted output to character array elements in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

I have an array of strings. I need to initialize each array element with some formatted data, i.e. each element should hold a constant string "data" plus a generated number. The final array should hold elements that look something like this, "data1", "data2", "data3", ... "dataN".

I used `sprintf()` but whenever the compile sees my `sprintf()` function, the program crashes. What am I doing wrong ?

```
//import necessary headers
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//variable to hold server data 
char *serverData[255];

//loop variable
int loop_index = 0;

//program entry
int main() {
    //initialize the serverData array elements with string "data" and
    //append number x to each element. i.e. x <= 255
    //use a for loop for the initialization
    for (; loop_index < sizeof(serverData) / sizeof(serverData[0]); loop_index++) {
        sprintf((char*)serverData[loop_index], "%s%d", "data", loop_index); //program crashes when this line is reached
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(char*)serverData[loop_index]` - Only cast if you 1) **fully** understand why the cast is required 2) Know **all** implications and 3) accept **all** effects.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is, you're using `serverData[n]` while it is not assigned  any *valid* memory. `char *serverData[255];` being a global array of pointer type, each member is implicitly initialized to a null pointer.

Refer `C11`, chapter §6.7.9,

> If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>   — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>   — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
>   and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>   - [.....]

A null pointer is not a valid one to access.

You need to allocate memory to `serverData[n]` before you can write to it. You can consider using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) to allocate memory to `serverData[n]` before you actually use it.

Answer (score 0):

Each pointer in your array is unitialized. Try this

```
#define NSERVERS    255
#define MAXDATA     32
char serverdata[MAXDATA][NSERVERS];

for (i = 0; i < NSERVERS; ++i)
    if (snprintf(serverdata[i], MAXDATA, "%s%d", "data", i) < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "snprintf returns <0\n");
```

`snprintf` is recommended over `sprintf`, because it doesn't allow buffer overflows to occur. In this code, each element is initialized--you can't just write onto a pointer. To remove the limits of this array, we could use `malloc`, and `realloc`.

Comment: Using 1) `snprintf()` and not checking its results vs . 2) `sprintf()` trades one class of errors for another.  Neither is recommended for robust code.

Comment: What's wrong with `sprintf` and `snprintf`? How does it trade one class of errors for another? What would be a better solutuon, then? @chux

Comment: What does `snprintf()` prevent that `sprintf()` may cause: buffer overflows.  What does `snprintf()` without error checking do: Creates un-flagged invalid data in a string.  `char s[22]; snprintf(s, sizeof s, "Release prisoner %d", 123456789);` --> `"Release prisoner 1234"`,  (Prisoner 1234 hates programmers) Simple check if the result of `snprintf(s, n, format,...)` is negative or `>= n` and then handle the error.

Comment: fixed [15 chars] @chux